# Class that needs to use containers as look-up tables. Should they be global variables or static members?

Tags: c++, class, static, containers, global

I apologize if I break any rules of this site in advance.  I just signed up to ask this.

Suppose I make a class.  It will have several strings for data members and some functions for some processing of those strings.

While processing occurs, a want to use the std::map containers for use as look-up tables.  The idea is, the map will just convert from one string into some other string, based on what the table says.

My question is basically, what would be the best way to do this?  I don't want the user of the class to even know about the tables; they are entirely hidden inside the implementation of the class.  That is why I am thinking I should probably make them private static members, but I am not sure.

I don't know if is allowed to do that or not.  In other words, where would I populate the maps?  I am guessing maybe in a .cpp file.

Anyway, any guidance would be appreciated.  And again, if this question is somewhere else, or I did anything wrong at this site, just get somebody to delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `map` will contain the same data for all instances of the `class` then a `private const std::map<std::string, std::string>` is sensible and can be initialised in the `.cpp` implementation file for the `class`:

```
// .h
class map_holder
{
public:
    std::string get(std::string const& a_name) const
    {
        auto i(m_.find(a_name));
        if (i != m_.end()) return i->second;
        return "";
    }
private:
    static const std::map<std::string, std::string> m_;
};

// .cpp
const std::map<std::string, std::string> map_holder::m_
    { { "one", "1" },
      { "two", "2" }
    };
```

If C++11 is unavailable use [`boost::assign::map_list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of):

```
const std::map<std::string, std::string> map_holder::m_ =
    boost::assign::map_list_of( "one", "1" )( "two", "2" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the map in your class, a simple example :

```
class YourClass
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
public:

    const std::string &get(const std::string &s) const
    {
        return m.at(s);
    }

    void put(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
    {
        m.insert(std::make_pair(s1, s2));
    }
};
```